# JavaScript Date constructor returns invalid date in CMS (server-side JS)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, content-management-system

I'm making an React app where I query Microsoft Graph API where I get the response date `2021-11-03T07:45:00.0000000`.

When I try to convert it to a JavaScript `Date` like this it gives me "invalid date" on `let date = new Date(dateString);`

```js
    let dateString = "2021-11-03T07:45:00.0000000"
    let date = new Date(dateString);
    let timezoneOffset = date.getTimezoneOffset();
    date.setMinutes(date.getMinutes() - timezoneOffset);
    let hours = date.getHours();
    let minutes = date.getMinutes();
    let formattedMinutes = minutes > 9 ? minutes : '0' + minutes;  
    console.log(hours + ':' + formattedMinutes);
```

This works in normal `JS` but the problem is that I use a **CMS** (server-side JS) that doesn't support `new Date(dateString)` so is it possible to format the date value to `8:45` without using **Date** constructor in **JS**? (`npm` libraries work in the CMS so if you have any solution with third party libraries it's fine.)

Answer (score 3):

A regex could help in this situation. This is a simple example when there is no timezone offset.

```js
str = '2021-11-03T07:45:00.0000000'

const time = str.match(/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}T([0-9:]{5})/)[1]

const timeFormatted = time.split(':').map(num => parseInt(num)).reduce((timeFormatted, num) => {
  if (timeFormatted) timeFormatted += ':'
  timeFormatted += num
  return timeFormatted
})

console.log(timeFormatted)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I do need the timezone difference...

Comment: what timezone do you want it in?

Comment: Central European time (CET)

Comment: looks like it observes daylight savings, so you'll have to check the date, add the timezone offset in the date string, and then add either 1 or 2 hours depending on whether it is daylight savings or not. Keep in mind this will stop working if daylight savings observance changes.

Comment: hmm, looks like your just getting the current time, not converting it from a string. Also, moment.js is deprecated, might look into Luxon or something more modern.